# Why does Quarkus warn me about injection in private fields?

Tags: quarkus

When I use something like the following in my Quarkus application:

```
@Path("v1")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloWorldResource {

   @Inject 
   private SomeBean someBean;
}
```

then I get a warning the following during the build process.

```
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor] Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
    - @Inject field acme.jaxrs.v1.HelloWorldResource#someBean
```

Everything seems to work just fine so why is Quarkus suggesting that change `private` to `package-private`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If a property is `package-private`, Quarkus can inject it directly without requiring any reflection to come into play.

That is why Quarkus recommends `package-private` members for injection as it tries to avoid reflection as much as possible (the reason for this being that less reflection means better performance which is something Quarkus strives to achieve).

See section 2 of [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference) guide for more details.

Comment: What do you suggest we do for Kotlin classes where package private is (still) not a  supported visibility modifier? Example `class ReactiveGreetingResource(@Inject var service: ReactiveGreetingService)`. Maybe even a bug in the `BeanProcessor` as it complains about "private members" when in fact it's public?

Comment: Yes, that is a false warning. Please open an issue

Comment: I meanwhile found https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10640 in which you addressed this.

Comment: To make the property *private-package*, simply delete the "private" modifier.

Comment: @GeraldScott In Kotlin, having no modifier makes a property public. There is no package-private in Kotlin.

Comment: Watch out for Client Proxies.  With @ConfigProperty, you should use private/getter/setter so that methods can be intercepted to add in the config values.